# Replacing a substring only if it is present outside the quotes not inside the quotes in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

```
/+(?=([^"\\]*(\\.|"([^"\\]*\\.)*[^"\\]*"))*[^"]*$)/g, "&&"
```

I used this regex it replaces + by && but how do i replace a string line "and" by "&&"

```
str = "Loop(this and that is "Help and enjoy")";
```

it should return: `Loop(this && that is "Help and enjoy")`

Comment: Simply substitute `+` with `and`? [Seems to work](http://www.regex101.com/r/gN2jV3)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just replacing `+`?

```
/(?:and)(?=([^"\\]*(\\.|"([^"\\]*\\.)*[^"\\]*"))*[^"]*$)/g, "&&"
```

Answer (score 1):

A way to do that is to match content in double quotes before:

```
var corr = {"and": "&&", "+": "&&"};

str.replace(/"[^"]+"|\+|\band\b/g, function(match) {
    return corr[match] || match;
});
```